# Songs being sung in Classical Latin literature

Tags: classical-latin

Listening to Classical Latin literature I have noticed what sounds like songs being sung! For example the Lydia Dic part in [Lydia Dic Per Omnes](http://www.stilus.nl/horatius/HorCarI-8LydiaDicPerOmnes.htm) and the *probās vocārī, Seu Genitālis* part of [Phoebe silvarumque potens Diana](http://www.stilus.nl/horatius/HorCar-CarmenSaeculare.htm)! It sounds like there is also a song being sung in the eō pertinent, ut ostendam part in the third part of Pliny's Panegyricus! http://www.stilus.nl/ce-geluid/PlinMinPan-LIII.htm Is there a reason why there are songs being sung in Classical Latin literature?

Comment: I think the only person who can answer that question is whoever made those recordings.

Comment: Just a note, these are more commonly called "*Odes* 1.8" (or sometimes *Carmina*) and the *Carmen Saeculare*. The [website](https://www.stilus.nl/horatius/) provides the first lines, but they're not the actual titles.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for the latter example, the *Carmen Saeculare* was indeed sung. From [here](https://www.csun.edu/%7Ehcfll004/ludisaec.html):

> Sacrificio perfecto puer. [X]XVII quibus denuntiatum erat patrimi et matrimi et puellae totidem|
> carmen cecinerunt; eo[de]m modo in Capitolio.|
> Carmen composuit Q. Hor[at]ius Flaccus.|

> After the sacrifice is completed, 27 boys for whom it had been made known that their parents were still alive, and just as many girls, sang the *Carmen [Saeculare]*. They similarly [sang it] on the Capitol. Q. Horatius Flaccus composed the *Carmen*.

Scholars are fairly unanimous in saying that this was a sung poem, not merely one spoken aloud, although in Barbara Gold & Genevieve Liveley's new book *A Guide to Roman Elegy and Lyric*, they claim that:

> Horace's *Odes* were never sung aloud (only his *Carmen Saeculare*, a choral ode, was sung). (p. 45)

If this is the case, then the first example you showed us is anachronistically sung.