# Did Classical Latin sound like singing at times like Italian does?

Tags: classical-latin, romance-languages, italian

Plesae note that this question is different from a previous question of mine! [Songs being sung in Classical Latin literature](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16952/songs-being-sung-in-classical-latin-literature)

Did Classical Latin sound like singing at times and if so did Classical Latin sound like singing for the same reasons that Italian does? For example: when Thomas Bervoets sounds like he's singing in Classical Latin when he sounds like he's singing In fīne ōrātiōnis in the sentence "In fīne ōrātiōnis praesidēs cūstōdēsque imperiī dīvōs ego cōnsul prō rēbus hūmānīs ac tē praecipuē, Capitōlīne Iuppiter, precor, ut beneficiīs tuīs faveās, tantīsque mūneribus addās perpetuitātem.", https://www.stilus.nl/ce-geluid/PlinMinPan-XCIV.htm the melody remind me of the melody that Luigi Miraglia sounds like he's singing in Italian when he sounds like he's singing quel fiore purpureo at 5:06 in the sentence "E questa verginità è forse anche quel fiore di cui parla un altro frammento, quel fiore purpureo calpestato dai pastori, qui l'immagine del fiore, l'immagine dei pastori ci dà senso della brutalità."! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpEemLDx2CQ&t=307s

I say sounds like because its rhythmic distribution of consonants and vowels contributes to its marked lilting sound, which is why speakers of other languages often say that Italian naturally sounds like singing!

Classical Latin evolved into Vulgar Latin which evolved into the Romance Languages including Italian!

Comment: Nice question! But beware, arguably every language and dialect sounds 'like singing' to some degree to foreign listeners: one just doesn't realize it in her own mother dialect. And, well, some languages' songs sound rougher, yet you can hear their intonation if you listen to expressive people, trained journalists, etc.